# Unable to Auto mapping in sitecore MVC(Razoe VIew) help of glass mapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, glass-mapper

Am using controller rendering, I created one model called Footer.cs and it has below properties.

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{1044CFB5-2B85-4A8D-9DCC-34764D2AF5B3}", AutoMap = true)]
public class Footer 
{
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
    [SitecoreField(FieldName ="Copyright Text First",FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText)]
    public virtual string CopyrightTextFirst { get; set; }

    [SitecoreField(FieldName ="Copyright Text Last",FieldType = SitecoreFieldType.SingleLineText)]
    public virtual string CopyrightTextLast { get; set; }
}
```

In My Controller:

```
public ActionResult FooterTemplate()
{
    ISitecoreContext ctx = new SitecoreContext();
    var model = ctx.GetCurrentItem<Footer>();
    return View(model);
}
```

But, always getting null result, please help me any one.

Comment: Could be any number of reasons. You need to show details on how your sitecore is configured.

Comment: Is the footer item your current "page" item or is it Datasource item?

Comment: It is data source item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
  public ActionResult FooterTemplate()
  {
    ISitecoreContext ctx = new SitecoreContext();
    var model = ctx.GetCurrentItem<Footer>(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource);
    return View(model);
  }
```

Comment: public ActionResult FooterTemplate()
        {
            ISitecoreContext ctx = new SitecoreContext();
            var model = ctx.GetItem<Footer>(ItemReferences.COPYRIGHT_TEXT);
            return View(model);
        }